# Ember app libraries initialization does not work

Tags: javascript, ember.js

We've got an Ember app and need to do some library initialization when rendering some templates.

1. **Google+**, **Facebook** and **Twitter** APIs for widgets. We do the initialization inside the `application` route, as well as inside each template that contains those specific widgets, for the use case when the user lands on that page directly. The problem is that Facebook and Twitter do not initialize at all when coming from another route. Google+, however, does. Also, if we refresh the page on which all 3 widgets reside, they all render correctly. The example below is a route called `blog` which also returns a model from the server API.

   ```
   renderTemplate: function ()
             {
               this._super();

               // initialize side nav drawer
               Ember.$(document).ready(function ()
                                       {
                                         Ember.$('.button-collapse').sideNav();
                                         Ember.$('select').material_select();
                                       });


               // load Google+ SDK
               Ember.$.getScript("https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js");

               // initialize Facebook SDK
               var facebook_id    = this.facebook_app_id;
               window.fbAsyncInit = function ()
               {
                 FB.init({
                   appId:   facebook_id,
                   xfbml:   true,
                   version: 'v2.1'
                 });
               };
               (function (d, s, id)
               {
                 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                 if (d.getElementById(id))
                 {
                   return;
                 }
                 js     = d.createElement(s);
                 js.id  = id;
                 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
                 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
               }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


               // load Twitter API
               window.twttr = (function (d, s, id)
               {
                 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], t = window.twttr || {};
                 if (d.getElementById(id))
                 {
                   return t;
                 }
                 js     = d.createElement(s);
                 js.id  = id;
                 js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
                 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

                 t._e    = [];
                 t.ready = function (f)
                 {
                   t._e.push(f);
                 };

                 return t;
               }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));
             }
   ```
2. **Materialize** side drawer (http://materializecss.com/). We need to initialize this globally, as it will be used when the user access the website from a smartphone or tablet. The problem here is that on routes which return models from our server API, the side drawer doesn't work, even though we do the initialization inside the `application` route, after the template is rendered. Why isn't it working on routes with models?

   ```
                    renderTemplate: function ()
             {
               this._super();
               Ember.$(document).ready(function ()
                                       {
                                         Ember.$('.button-collapse').sideNav();
                                         Ember.$('select').material_select();
                                       });}
   ```

Answer (score 0):

So apparently there is no way of using a callback for when the route ends with all the rendering in order to initialize/parse UI elements at that moment. Which kinda sucks. Then again, much of how the web and JS frameworks work, sucks. So nothing out of the ordinary here.

Anyway, the solution is to use `Ember Components`, which build upon Web Components. Just wrap your UI widget HTML code inside a component; in our case, we moved the Facebook Share button, the Facebook Page Widget, the Twitter share button and the Materialize side navigation button HTML inside the component templates (`/templates/components/example-widget.hbs`). Then create the associated component at `/components/example-widget.js`. This should also contain a `didInsertElement` callback. Just put your code inside that callback and you should be fine.